# JSON and jQuery listview

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

Im trying to add rows(that will match the format) to listview from json (from the response):

```
results : { _id: 53f8c48ddc1f5f0419f2ed53,
  bName: 'Microsoft',
  phone: 35588319,
  Email: 'microsoft@gmail.com',
  field: 'QA',
  exp: '0-2',
  __v: 0,
  location: [ { longitude: 7.8, latitude: 7.8, _id: 53f8c48ddc1f5f0419f2ed54 } ] }end
```

and my table is :

```
<table summary="This table lists all the Jobs." cellpadding="40" cellspacing="40" vspace="40">
    <caption id = "jobsListView" >
        JOBS
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Contact</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Field</th>
            <th scope="col">Exp</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- every row = a row in the file 
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Microsoft</th> // comapny name
            <td>0508558319</td> // contact
            <td>Microsoft@mcsf.com (JFK)</td> // email 
            <td>QA (JFK)</td> // field 
            <td>0-2 (JFK)</td> // exp
        </tr>

       -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

so bName = company name , phone = contact ...  without the location .

and i send\rec by ajax :

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      url:'http://localhost:3000/find',
      data: workerInfo, 
     success: function(jobs){
      }
    });
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: How to add rows to my table according to the json file ? (bName = company name , contact = phone ...)  , just how to add rows to a listview.

Comment: is the response you are getting is array of objects?

Comment: No , i get a json  like shown above (results ).

Comment: Yes, but does the returning JSON has object of arrays i.e. `[{},{}.{}]`or only single object? `{}`?

Comment: It will be great if u will show me both cases (single and array).

Comment: Sure, updating answer in few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose if the response is array of objects -

```
var $body = $("table tbody"); //select table (change ID / class if required anad locate to tbody)
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      url:'http://localhost:3000/find',
      data: workerInfo, 
      success: function(response){ 
          var jobs = JSON.parse(response); //parse the response.
          $.each(jobs, function(j, e) { //every object represents row so iterate thru it
              //generate table row 
              var row='<tr>';
              row+='<td>'+e.bName+'</td>';
              row+='<td>'+e.phone+'</td>';
              row+='<td>'+e.Email+'</td>';
              row+='<td>'+e.field+'</td>';
              row+='<td>'+e.exp+'</td>';
              row+='</tr>';   
              $body.append(row); //Append it to tbody
          });
      }
});
```

And if the response is single object -

```
var $body = $("table tbody"); //select table (change ID / class if required anad locate to tbody)
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      url:'http://localhost:3000/find',
      data: workerInfo, 
      success: function(response){ 
          var jobs = JSON.parse(response); //Parse the response
              //generate table row 
              var row='<tr>';
              row+='<td>'+jobs.bName+'</td>';
              row+='<td>'+jobs.phone+'</td>';
              row+='<td>'+jobs.Email+'</td>';
              row+='<td>'+jobs.field+'</td>';
              row+='<td>'+jobs.exp+'</td>';
              row+='</tr>';   
              $body.append(row); //Append it to tbody
      }
});
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: still dont work .. i have tried to change the $body selector to var $body = $("#tbody"); the id on the <tbody id = "tbody"> , still with no results .

Comment: Does `$body = $("#tbody")` find the object, try console logging it?

Comment: Also, console log the `row` before append line.. tell me what it is!

Comment: thats the console.log output : [tbody#tbody, prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1], context: document, selector: "tbody", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function…]
0: tbody#tbody
context: document
length: 1
prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1]
selector: "tbody"
__proto__: Object[0]

Comment: can you try replacing `var jobs = JSON.parse(response)` with `var jobs = response`?

Comment: without the JSON.parse ?

Comment: tried that , also add $body.append(row); //Append it to tbody
                console.log("OK"); and the console is empty

Comment: can you come on chat? ok you can't..anyway.. console.log(response) and see what you get.

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(response))  - does not  shows at devolpertools\console  - $body(console.log($body)) is the only one there

Comment: Nope, print `console.log(response)` not `console.log(JSON.parse(response))`

Comment: Tried that as well..  Is there any chance that success function dosnt work?

Comment: Possible.  Check network tab and see what response u get

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas can you at least print anything in success callback? like console.log("hello from success"); check it..

Comment: that the response that appear at devolperTools\network\response to that GET request :results : { _id: 53f8c48ddc1f5f0419f2ed53,
  bName: 'Microsoft',
  phone: 35588319,
  Email: 'microsoft@gmail.com',
  field: 'QA',
  exp: '0-2',
  __v: 0,
  location: [ { longitude: 7.8, latitude: 7.8, _id: 53f8c48ddc1f5f0419f2ed54 } ] }end , and no , i cant print anything after the success function start .

Comment: I narrowed down what the problem could be : 1)dom elements don't get values 2)success isnt starting

Comment: Can you please post exact ajax code / possibly javascript code in question? I want to take a close look at it.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas remove `dataType: 'JSON'` from ajax request, I think the problem persist there since I think the response we are getting is not a valid JSON.. try it

Comment: Got it, the response has invalid JSON that's why ajax is not firing success. It is expecting JSON dataset as a response.

Comment: do u have a email ? i will send u the all project include server side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59945/discussion-between-itsik-mauyhas-and-rahul-patil).